# Issues setting the local admin account password to not allowed to be changed

Tags: command-line, windows-10, passwords, administrator

I need to be able to set a local admin account with the /passwordchg:No option in windows. I have soon found out that Windows 10 have disabled this feature and I have tried multiple different ways to bypass this but have had many issues, For example...

```
C:\Users\TEST MACHINE>wmic useraccount where name='Administrator' set passwordchangeable=false

Updating property(s) of '\\DESKTOP-8MANOCA\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="DESKTOP-8MANOCA",Name="Administrator"'

ERROR:
Description = Generic failure

C:\Users\TEST MACHINE>net user administrator /passwordchg:no
System error 1322 has occurred.

This operation is disallowed as it could result in an administration account being disabled, deleted or unable to logon.
```

I need to disable this feature to secure the local admin account as I have been testing on machines and if I have admin rights I can change the password.... Any advice would be appreciated. I would try anything SCCM WMIC GP ect.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished for administrator accounts that are not the actual built-in administrator account.

1. Log in with a different administrator account than the one targeted. For example, log in as administrator
2. Launch Computer Management (compmgmt.msc)
3. Navigate to "Local Users and Groups" -> "Users"
4. Right click the user, click "Properties".
5. Navigate to "Member Of" tab and remove the "Administrators" group
6. Click apply
7. Navigate to "General" tab, check box for "User cannot change password"
8. Click apply
9. Navigate to "Member Of" tab and re-add the "Administrators" group
10. Click OK

Comment: Did you mean to write this as an answer?